# (PySide6) How to open a window on secondary display?

Tags: display, pyside6

I want to open a pyside6 app on a secondary display.
(I am using triple monitors.)

I have tried QWidget.setScreen method like below.

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.setScreen(app.screens()[1])
w.show()
```

But it didn't work.

Through app.screens(), I get the list of monitors connected. However, my app always opens on the primary display.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

I hope the answer is not too late...

I also forgot to move the window like you.
For me it worked :

```
app = QApplication()
w = MainWindow()
w.setScreen(app.screens()[1])

screen = w.screen()

w.move(screen.geometry().topLeft())
w.showMaximized()
app.exec()
```

Comment: great answer! Worked flawlessly. Thanks :)